# how to install virtualbox on RHEL 6 without using yum?

Tags: virtualbox, rhel6

My company has firewall rules for yum so we can use only rpm to install the softwares on the RHEL 6 SERVER. So, I got a task to install virtualbox 5.1 on it. i used the rpm from the virtualbox website and installed it, but it failed with 2 dependencies and i installed them also. Then i got the below error.I just googled that i need some kernel-devel rpms but i dono, what to do after that and what else i need to make the virtual box running.

```
# virtualbox
  WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module available for the current kernel (2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64) or it failed to load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

       sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

Qt FATAL: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Aborted

Comment: why does anyone wont reply for my questions, if something is wrong please tell me i will correct

Comment: Stack Overflow is for **programming questions**. As your question is not about programming, you will get better responses if ask it on more appropriate site. E.g., on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

There will be lot of dependencies while installing rpm's. you need to check one by one and install the RPM's. Is suggest you to build local yum repository which doesnt require internet. you should use rhel 6 iso file to build local repo. And download the virtual box rpm, and try to install it with yum utility. yum will use local repo for dependency resolution.

Build repo:
1. mount DVD

```
[root@lh1 Packages]# cd /etc/yum.repos.d
[root@lh1 yum.repos.d]# vi dvd.repo
[root@lh1 yum.repos.d]# cat dvd.repo
[DVD_ISO]
name= Linux 6
baseurl=file:///mnt/cdrom
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
[root@lh1 rpm-gpg]# yum clean all
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin


[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6Server'

[root@lh1 rpm-gpg]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
This system is not registered with ULN.
ULN support will be disabled.
DVD_ISO                                                                                                      | 3.7 kB     00:00 ...
DVD_ISO/primary_db                                                                                           | 3.1 MB     00:00 ...
repo id                                                    repo name                                                          status
DVD_ISO                                                    Linux 6                                                     3,379
repolist: 3,379
```